# Unit testing Cloud Functions for Firebase: what's the "right way" to test/mock `transaction`s with sinon.js

Tags: unit-testing, firebase, sinon, google-cloud-functions, sinon-chai

Man, this firebase unit testing is really kicking my butt.

I've gone through [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing) and read through the examples that they provide, and have gotten some of my more basic Firebase functions unit tested, but I keep running into problems where I'm not sure how to verify that the `transactionUpdated` function passed along to the refs `.transaction` is correctly updating the `current` object.

My struggle is probably best illustrated with their [`child-count` sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/child-count/functions/index.js) and a poor attempt I made at writing a unit test for it.

Let's say my function that I want to unit test does the following (taken straight from that above link):

```
// count.js
exports.countlikechange = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postid}/likes/{likeid}').onWrite(event => {
      const collectionRef = event.data.ref.parent;
      const countRef = collectionRef.parent.child('likes_count');

      // ANNOTATION: I want to verify the `current` value is incremented
      return countRef.transaction(current => {
        if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
          return (current || 0) + 1;
        }
        else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
          return (current || 0) - 1;
        }
      }).then(() => {
        console.log('Counter updated.');
      });
    });
```

Unit Test Code:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const assert = chai.assert;
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('Cloud Functions', () => {
  let myFunctions, functions;

  before(() => {
    functions = require('firebase-functions');
    myFunctions = require('../count.js');
  });

  describe('countlikechange', () => {
    it('should increase /posts/{postid}/likes/likes_count', () => {
      const event = {
        // DeltaSnapshot(app: firebase.app.App, adminApp: firebase.app.App, data: any, delta: any, path?: string);
        data: new functions.database.DeltaSnapshot(null, null, null, true)
      }

      const startingValue = 11
      const expectedValue = 12

      // Below code is misunderstood piece.  How do I pass along `startingValue` to the callback param of transaction
      // in the `countlikechange` function, and spy on the return value to assert that it is equal to `expectedValue`?
      // `yield` is almost definitely not the right thing to do, but I'm not quite sure where to go.
      // How can I go about "spying" on the result of a stub,
      // since the stub replaces the original function?
      // I suspect that `sinon.spy()` has something to do with the answer, but when I try to pass along `sinon.spy()` as the yields arg, i get errors and the `spy.firstCall` is always null. 
      const transactionStub = sinon.stub().yields(startingValue).returns(Promise.resolve(true))

      const childStub = sinon.stub().withArgs('likes_count').returns({
        transaction: transactionStub
      })
      const refStub = sinon.stub().returns({ parent: { child: childStub }})

      Object.defineProperty(event.data, 'ref', { get: refStub })

      assert.eventually.equals(myFunctions.countlikechange(event), true)
    })
  })
})
```

I annotated the source code above with my question, but I'll reiterate it here.

How can I verify that the [`transactionUpdate` callback](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction), passed to the transaction stub, will take my `startingValue` and mutate it to `expectedValue` and then allow me to observe that change and assert that it happened.

This is probably a very simple problem with an obvious solution, but I'm very new to testing JS code where everything has to be stubbed, so it's a bit of a learning curve... Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

I agree that unit testing in the Firebase ecosystem isn't as easy as we'd like it to be. The team is aware of it, and we're working to make things better! Fortunately, there *are* some good ways forward for you right now!

I suggest taking a look at [this Cloud Functions demo](https://github.com/laurenzlong/say-that/tree/master/functions) that we've just published. In that example we use TypeScript, but this'll all work in JavaScript too.

In the `src` directory you'll notice we've split out the logic into three files: `index.ts` has the entry-logic, `saythat.ts` has our main business-logic, and `db.ts` is a thin abstraction layer around the Firebase Realtime Database. We unit-test only `saythat.ts`; we've intentionally kept `index.ts` and `db.ts` really simple.

In the `spec` directory we have the unit tests; take a look at `index.spec.ts`. The trick that you're looking for: we [use](https://github.com/laurenzlong/say-that/blob/master/functions/spec/fake-db.ts#L2) `mock-require` to mock out the entire `src/db.ts` file and replace it with `spec/fake-db.ts`. Instead of writing to the real database, we now store our performed operations in-memory, where our unit test can check that they look correct. A concrete example is our `score` field, which is [updated in a transaction](https://github.com/laurenzlong/say-that/blob/master/functions/src/saythat.ts#L137). By [mocking](https://github.com/laurenzlong/say-that/blob/master/functions/spec/index.spec.ts#L12) the database, our unit test to check that that's done correctly is [a single line of code](https://github.com/laurenzlong/say-that/blob/master/functions/spec/index.spec.ts#L142).

I hope that helps you do your testing!

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for the resources and response.  Apart from testing, i've been incredibly impressed with the Cloud Functions product, really powerful stuff - the documentation is generally good too, just lacking in the testing department.  Great work to you and your team.

Comment: Thanks tim! Let us know if you run into any more issues. We're eager to make everything awesome. :)

Comment: @Robert-JanHuijsman I'm also really impressed with firebase, I've devoted the last 3 days on it as I think this is going to be the future of backend for me and many others. One thing that I wish you had was a road map. So we can know on what you are working.

Comment: Great to hear! Your request for a roadmap is noted! In the mean time, I suggest signing up for our Alpha program - that'll give you a sneak peek into much of the cool tech that we're working on: firebase.google.com/alpha